Is there a Postgres string value that compares greater/less than all other strings?
I'm looking for a value in Postgres similar to "-infinity"/"infinity", but for string values, which can be used in a WHERE clause, for example, WHERE "name" > 'infinity', which should always return false. Ideally, this value would work regardless of collation or locale settings.
I've looked through the Postgres documentation, but it's very long, so I'm not confident that I just missed something or used the wrong search terms.
My need for this value is specifically to get around some problematic behavior I'm experiencing with NULL string values. Essentially, I'm trying to mimic the "NULLS LAST" behavior of ORDER BY, but in a WHERE clause.
Background
I am trying to implement keyset pagination in Postgres with support for multi-column, non unique indexes, using Row Constructor Comparison.
Here is an example table I am testing with:
CREATE table (
   id text PRIMARY KEY,
   name text 
);

And a corresponding query:
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ("name", "id") > ($1, $2)
ORDER BY "name", "id"
LIMIT 5

This almost works, but the query never returns any rows with a null "name".
Additionally, I can't simply add OR "name" IS NULL to the end of the WHERE clause, because then the query always returns all the null rows, and it is not possible to paginate through several pages of results with null names, but distinct ids.
Another question offered a simple solution to the problem, use coalesce to convert NULL values to an arbitrary string larger than my data ("ZZZZZZZ").
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (COALESCE("name", 'ZZZZZZZ'), "id") > (COALESCE($1, 'ZZZZZZZ'), $2)
ORDER BY "name", "id"
LIMIT 5

This solution works pretty well--the row comparison semantics are correct for pagination, and the query is very simple to construct dynamically--but it seems impossible to select an appropriate "largest" string for my data.
For an arbitrary length text column, there is no "largest" literal string I can insert here, so there are always inputs that could cause my query to fail. Additionally, the "last" character I need to use depends on the locale and collation options configured on the database. I'm sure that in my real data, 'ZZZZZZZ' would be a terrible choice.

I don't think there is any such string value. However, I found that Postgres puts NULLs last when comparing array elements (determined experimentally), so you can use
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE (ARRAY["name"], "id") > (ARRAY[$1::text], $2::int)
ORDER BY "name" NULLS LAST, "id"
LIMIT 5

A maybe better (more straightforward and standards-compliant) solution  is to introduce a third element in your row that has a higher precedence than the nullable one:
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE ("name" IS NULL, COALESCE("name", ''), "id") > ($1::text IS NULL, COALESCE($1::text, ''), $2::int)
ORDER BY "name" NULLS LAST, "id"
LIMIT 5


Very interesting solutions, thank you! It also hadn't occurred to me that the empty string is the "minimum" string, which seems obvious in hindsight. Of course, an empty string may hypothetically still be a valid value in the data, distinct from NULL, but in practice not so much (and no different from "infinity" in that respect anyway).

Doesn't really matter what you use in the COALESCE in the second approach. It's just that (true, '', id_1) will always be larger than (false, 'somestring', id_2)
